# Error compiling C code with Make 'ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64'

Tags: c, gcc, linker, makefile

I'm trying to compile a C program on OS X using Make but get an error message.

## C Code

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE // required for cuserid to work

// includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <time.h>

// user-defined constants
#define FIB_MAX_ITERS 20
#define SLEEP_LENGTH 2

// Prints an error message and exits if one occurs. Else, returns the system call value.
int print_if_err(int syscall_val)
{
    if (syscall_val < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(errno);
    } else {
        // No syscall error; we can return.
        return syscall_val;
    }
}

char* cuserid_wrapper()
{
    char* val = cuserid(NULL);
    if (val == NULL) {
        perror("cuserid");
        exit(errno);
    } else {
        return val;
    }
}

time_t time_wrapper()
{
    time_t val = time(NULL);
    if (val == ((time_t) -1)) {
        perror("time_wrapper");
        exit(errno);
    } else {
        return val;
    }
}

void getrusage_wrapper(struct rusage* output)
{
    int val = getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, output);
    if (val == -1){
        perror("getrusage_wrapper");
        exit(errno);
    }
}

void print_uids_gids(const char* proc_name)
{
    printf("[%s] username: %s\n", proc_name, cuserid_wrapper());

    // According to man pages, following syscalls always succeed. 
    // Hence, no error checking
    printf("[%s] user id: %d\n",  proc_name, getuid()); 
    printf("[%s] effective user id: %d\n", proc_name, geteuid());
    printf("[%s] group id: %d\n",  proc_name, getgid());
    printf("[%s] effective group id: %d\n", proc_name, getegid());
    printf("[%s] pid: %d\n", proc_name, getpid());
}

void print_exec_times(const char* proc_name)
{
    // build up some cpu time
    int k = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        k += 2;
    }

    time_t cur_time;
    struct rusage res_usage;

    cur_time = time_wrapper();
    getrusage_wrapper(&res_usage);

    printf("[%s] seconds since epoch: %d\n", proc_name, (int)cur_time);
    printf("[%s] current time: %s", proc_name, ctime(&cur_time));
    printf("[%s] user CPU time: %d us\n", proc_name, (int)res_usage.ru_utime.tv_usec);
    printf("[%s] system CPU time: %d us\n", proc_name, (int)res_usage.ru_stime.tv_usec);
}

void sleep_wrapper(unsigned int length)
{
    int time_left = length;
    while (time_left > 0) {
        time_left = sleep(length);
    }
}

char* getcwd_wrapper()
{
    char* cwd = getcwd(NULL, 0);
    if (cwd == NULL) {
        perror("getcwd_wrapper");
        exit(errno);
    } else {
        return cwd;
    }
}

void waitpid_wrapper(pid_t pid)
{
    int status;
    int val = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    if (val == -1) {
        perror("waitpid_wrapper");
        exit(errno);
    } 
}

void child_proc(int fib_start, const char* proc_name)
{
    print_uids_gids(proc_name);
    // No errors can occur for getppid
    printf("[%s] parent PID: %d\n", proc_name, getppid());

    sleep(SLEEP_LENGTH); // sleep to align fibonacci prints
    // main loop - printing fibonacci numbers
    int f_prev = 1; // starts at f_1
    int f_cur = 1; // starts at f_2
    int f_cur_new;
    int f_prev_new;
    int i;
    for (i = fib_start; i <= FIB_MAX_ITERS; i += 2) { // want <= b/c 1-based index
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            printf("[%s] f_%d = %d\n", proc_name, i, f_prev);
        } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
            printf("[%s] f_%d = %d\n", proc_name, i, f_cur);
        }

        f_cur_new  =  2 * f_cur + f_prev;
        f_prev_new = f_cur + f_prev;
        f_cur  = f_cur_new;
        f_prev = f_prev_new;

        sleep(SLEEP_LENGTH);
    }

    print_exec_times(proc_name);
    exit(0);
}

char* get_proc_name(const char* base, char* buff)
{
    sprintf(buff, "%s, PID=%d", base, (int)getpid());
    return (char*)buff;
}

int main(void)
{
    char parent_proc_name[255];
    get_proc_name("parent", parent_proc_name);
    // TODO: Error check the syscalls!
    printf("[%s] current working directory: %s\n",  parent_proc_name, getcwd_wrapper());
    print_uids_gids(parent_proc_name);

    pid_t child1_pid = print_if_err(fork());
    if (child1_pid == 0) {
        sleep(SLEEP_LENGTH / 2);

        char proc_name[255];
        get_proc_name("child1", proc_name);
        child_proc(1, proc_name);
    }
    printf("[%s] child1_pid: %d\n", parent_proc_name, child1_pid);

    pid_t child2_pid = print_if_err(fork());
    if (child2_pid == 0) {
        sleep(SLEEP_LENGTH);

        char proc_name[255];
        get_proc_name("child2", proc_name);
        child_proc(2, proc_name);
    }
    printf("[%s] child2_pid: %d\n", parent_proc_name, child1_pid);

    int status;
    // TODO: Error check the syscalls!
    waitpid(child1_pid, &status, 0);
    printf("[%s] child1 terminated\n", parent_proc_name);
    waitpid(child2_pid, &status, 0);
    printf("[%s] child2 terminated\n", parent_proc_name);
    print_exec_times(parent_proc_name);
    return 0;
}
```

## Make File

```
CC = gcc
C_FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra

all: eecs338_hw01

eecs338_hw01: eecs338_hw01.o
    $(CC) eecs338_hw01.o -o eecs338_hw01

eecs338_hw01.o: eecs338_hw01.c
    $(CC) -c $(C_FLAGS) eecs338_hw01.c

clean:
    rm -f eecs338_hw01 eecs338_hw01.o
```

## Error

```
gcc eecs338_hw01.o -o eecs338_hw01
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cuserid", referenced from:
      _cuserid_wrapper in eecs338_hw01.o
     (maybe you meant: _cuserid_wrapper)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [eecs338_hw01] Error 1
```

Comment: You should set `_XOPEN_SOURCE 700` (or `600`), not simply define it.  However that shouldn't affect linking, only whether the symbol is visible in the headers.

Comment: You should also read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  This is not an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` (or 600), not simply define it. However that shouldn't affect linking, only whether the symbol is visible in the headers.

Running `man cuserid` on Mac OS X reveals that there is no man page for the function.

Compiling your code with my normal options:

```
 gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
     -Wold-style-definition -Werror cuserid.c -o cuserid
```

required me to make some minor changes to your code.  The functions are made `static` so there isn't a need for a separate prototype, and the function definitions use an explicit `void` to indicate no arguments:

```
char* cuserid_wrapper(void)
```

instead of:

```
char* cuserid_wrapper()
```

Those are relatively minor issues (more or less normal when you don't develop with such stringent compilation options). With those changes made, I get left being told that `sleep_wrapper()` and `waitpid_wrapper()` are defined but unused (proving once more that this is not an MCVE). I also get:

```
cuserid.c:33:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'cuserid' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration].
```

Given that, it is not very surprising that the linking fails; the system doesn't know about the `cuserid()` function. I observe that `cuserid()` is not currently a part of [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm). The Linux man page for [`cuserid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/cuserid) notes:

> System V has a `cuserid()` function which uses the real user ID rather than the effective user ID. The `cuserid()` function was included in the 1988 version of POSIX, but removed from the 1990 version. It was present in SUSv2, but removed in POSIX.1-2001.

#### TL;DR

The `cuserid()` function is not portable and doesn't port to Mac OS X.